# JVM Performance while invoking it with -d64 option

Tags: java, jvm, solaris

Recently I had an issue in allocating 4GB of Heap to my java process on Solaris 11. However that got resolved when I invoked java process with -d64 option. Now this introduced a new performance problem of degraded application response time. Can anybody guide me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24936/tuning-java.htm

Answer (score 1):

The larger heap is, the more time garbage collector needs to traverse it. Which one are you using? Whats your JVM version? Try switch to CMS collector, its a low latency one. Here are some links on this topic:

- [Short description of GC algorithms and parameters](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors)
- [Tuning manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `-d64` argument will just make your VM run in a 64-bit environment.

Although indirectly, the 64-bit mode may have a negative impact on your performance (larger memory footprint of objects, larger heap), I do not believe that this alone introduced any substantial slowdown into your application. To rule out this, you should check your GC logs for any changes in the GC activity after introducing the `-d64`.

In any case, you need to provide some details about the application and the slowdown observed in order to identify the actual cause of the problem.